# SELECT items from DB comparing to latest date in another table

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to select all items from `userLogTable` where the record is newer than the latest matching item in `activityTable`. I would like to do this in a single query.

Currently I select from one table and then loop through the results while matching against another table.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Visits, userLogTable.* FROM userLogTable GROUP BY Name, Date

userLogTable
Name   | Surname | Date
-----------------------------
Dave   | Smith   | 2016-06-01
Jane   | Doe     | 2016-06-01
Dave   | Smith   | 2016-06-02
Dave   | Smith   | 2016-06-01
Jane   | Doe     | 2016-06-03
Peter  | Bloggs  | 2016-06-03
Steve  | Foo     | 2016-06-01
Steve  | Foo     | 2016-06-01
// many more rows

// above SQL returns the following result as expected/needed
Name   | Surname |  Date       | Visits
----------------------------------------
Dave   | Smith   |  2016-06-01 | 2
Jane   | Doe     |  2016-06-01 | 1
Dave   | Smith   |  2016-06-02 | 1
Jane   | Doe     |  2016-06-03 | 1
Peter  | Bloggs  |  2016-06-03 | 1
Steve  | Foo     |  2016-06-01 | 2

activityTable
Name   | Surname | Date
------------------------------
Dave   | Smith   | 2016-06-03
Dave   | Smith   | 2016-06-03
Dave   | Smith   | 2016-06-03
Dave   | Smith   | 2016-06-02
Dave   | Smith   | 2016-06-02
Dave   | Smith   | 2016-06-02
Dave   | Smith   | 2016-06-01
Dave   | Smith   | 2016-05-29
Dave   | Smith   | 2016-05-29
// many more rows
```

**QUERY:**

```
foreach($userLogTableResult as $key => $val) {
    // db function
    SELECT Date 
    FROM activityTable  
    WHERE Date > $latestDateFromUserLogTable 
      AND NAME = $val['Name'] 
      AND Surname = $val['Surname'] 
    ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 1 
    // if there is a result then unset this item as it's older than the latest activity
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The code above has been extensively simplified for this example. I am building the SQL and parsing it into a custom PDO function. All values are escaped and sanitised accordingly.

Comment: newer or same date? because `Dave   | Smith   | 2016-06-01` newer is only 1 and your result show 2 .... And what determinate `matching item` I dont see any `ID`

Comment: `userLogTable` needs to be a newer record than the `activityTable`. My SQL example isn't limiting it by date, it is pulling everything in. My php loop then removes where required. I haven't posted the output of the php loop.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: without a time how you determinate who is the newer?

Comment: Your tables seem to lacking PRIMARY KEYs. Despite GL's enthusaism, this problem is insoluble.

Comment: Please provide a better explanation for your logic. You **cant** say your query provide result as need it because then you question is already solve. You need to provide db schema, sample data, current result and expected result, Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: @Strawberry there are id's. indexes and primary keys within the tables I am using. I have simplified the table setup for this question. In reality the The matching columns between all tables are the `Name` and `Surname`.

Comment: In which case, you have over-simplified the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
select ult.*
from userLogTable ult
where ult.date > (select max(a.date)
                  from activityTable a
                  where a.name = ult.name and a.surname = ult.surname
                 ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks, just testing this out. What would be the outcome if no record is found in `activityTable `? Would it consider `ult.date` greater than a `NULL` value? Comparing to NULL values in my experience has had unexpected results at times :/

Comment: @steve . . . If no activity is found, then the subquery returns `NULL` and the row is filtered out.